# C-shell: find file more that 12 hours

Tags: find, csh

I am using solaris and i need to find file that more than 12 hours.
In solaris, there is no -mmin function. So, what i do is:

```
set timer = "/admin/timer.txt"
echo date > $timer

find . -type ! newer  $timer
```

But this only work I set the script run every 12 hours. 
The thing is I need to run the script every 1 hours but I couldn't find a way how to do it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you make your script into a cron job?

Comment: yes...i already tried to set it at cronjob..the one that i post is only part of the script.

Comment: sorry, i mistype.. the script should run every 1 hours instead every 12 hours

Comment: Show the relevant line from cron. Keep in mind that you have to set (all) your environment variables when running from cron (it runs a bare-bones shell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke a shell function to do the test.  Something like:

```
now=$(perl -e 'print time')
find . -exec sh -c 'expr $1 - $(stat -f %m "$2" ) \< 43200 > /dev/null' _ $now {}  \; -print
```